# How can get value from the added input field in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a value example 50. If my value 50 is small then a new field should be added and then take value from the added fields and both value equal to not 50 then add new fields and get again value and continue... when my value will be large from the 50.

Please suggest me...

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var inMain = $('#mainNumber').val();
    var inMain1 = $('#mainNumber1').val();
    var inMain2 = $('#mainNumber2').val();
    var inMain3 = $('#mainNumber3').val();
    var inMain4 = $('#mainNumber4').val();
    var inMain5 = $('#mainNumber5').val();
    
    if(inMain<36){
      $('.my1box').show();
    } else if((inMain+inMain1) < 36) {
      $('.my2box').show();
    } else if((inMain+inMain1+inMain2) < 36) {
      $('.my3box').show();
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
[class$="box"] {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my">
  Main <input type="number" id="mainNumber">
</div>

<div class="my1box">
  1 <input type="number" id="mainNumber1">
</div>

<div class="my2box">
  2 <input type="number" id="mainNumber2">
</div>

<div class="my3box">
  3 <input type="number" id="mainNumber3">
</div>
<div class="my4box">
  4 <input type="number" id="mainNumber4">
</div>
<div class="my5box">
 5 <input type="number" id="mainNumber5">
</div>

<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var total = 0;
  var inputs = $('input');
  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    total += parseInt($(inputs[i]).val());
  }
  if(total < 50) {
    $('.my1box').append(`<input type="number">`);
  } else {
    console.log("Finally your total score more than 50, Total Score:", total);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my">
  Main <input type="number">
</div>

<div class="my1box"></div>

<button>Submit</button>
```

Hope this will help you.

Explanation: Your new inputs will be appended into `my1box` container.

Just loop through all the inputs & add the value then check for the total value. If the value is less than 50 then add one more input box to `my1box` container.

**Updated answer**

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var total = 0;
  var inputs = $('input.month');
  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    total += parseInt($(inputs[i]).val());
  }
  if(total < 36) {
    $('.my1box').append(`
      <input type="text" placeholder="Current Address" />
      <br/>Month
      <input type="number" class="month">`);
  } else {
    console.log("Finally your total score more than 36, Total Score:", total);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Current Address" />
  <br />
  Month <input type="number" class="month">
</div>

<div class="my1box"></div>

<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for you support,
My concern that if my months value will be greater than 36 then will be form should be submitted other wise in less than again show my three fields and fill the address...untill not get last 36 month address. I hope got my points.

Comment: I think it would be for more understandable.
Please see screenshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=17VwkjtWrsZc8COglM_2v-Qz5jFQJ77eI